# Training Tesseract on Android

Tags: android, api, ocr, tesseract, training-data

I am using the [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) library for OCR recognition on Android . I want to create the training data on Android . I have followed this [link](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3) and successfully created training data on linux system . How to do the same on Android using tess-two or any other library ?

Answer (score 1):

The tess-two library for Android uses the same Tesseract code and the same training data format as is run on plain Linux systems. You can just swap in your trained data files.

Comment: I have tried using tess-two library but is it possible to generate trained data files on android ?

Comment: No. You need to do the training on a desktop computer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder in the sd card of your phone where you are making the address at the program. After that using samsun kies or any other type of file manager for android you could upload the tessdata into this folder. The folder need to have the same address you specified in your code