# Training Tesseract data for android difficult to achieve?

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

Recently I made a simple Tesseract app with tess-two for android. 
But the numbers I get from the image is terrible and I would need some help with making traineddata for android. Or if possible are there a good traineddata for numbers that I can download ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe looking at these two links are worth the merit and that they will certainly bring you closer to an answer. Additionally I do not believe that there is any trainingdata particularly for numbers floating around online somewhere (As I have not found them myself). The links:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/zOPKly6ymbA
https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_recognize_only_digits

and this link especially 
[Training Tesseract on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192606/training-tesseract-on-android)